# Memory Error using lambda function with array

Tags: c++, lambda

```
const int bookBoatNum = 10;
Wt::WPushButton *buttonBookBoat[bookBoatNum];
Wt::WDialog *dialogBookBoat[bookBoatNum];

for (int i = 1; i < bookBoatNum; i++){
    dialogBookBoat[i] = new Wt::WDialog("Book Boat");
    buttonBookBoat[i] = new Wt::WPushButton();

    buttonBookBoat[i]->clicked().connect(std::bind([&dialogBookBoat,i]() {
        dialogBookBoat[i]->show();
    }));
}
```

The program compiles and runs. When I click on a WPushButton object, it crashes because of the third last line because of a memory error. This code works perfectly if buttonBookBoat and dialogBookBoat are single objects, rather than an array of objects. show() is a method that displays the dialog object.

Any help is appreciated, this error has been driving me crazy and my life is on the line with this code (not really).

Comment: So both buttonBookBoat and dialogBookBoat exist for sure when the button is pushed?  If they are both global then they do but you don't say what scope they have.

Comment: Jerry Jeremiah Yes, they both exist. I tried the exact same code with a single object, as opposed to an array, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const int bookBoatNum = 10;
Wt::WPushButton *buttonBookBoat[bookBoatNum];
Wt::WDialog *dialogBookBoat[bookBoatNum];

for (int i = 1; i < bookBoatNum; i++){
    dialogBookBoat[i] = new Wt::WDialog("Book Boat");
    Wt::WDialog * tempDialog=new Wt::WPushButton();
    buttonBookBoat[i] = tempDialog;

    buttonBookBoat[i]->clicked().connect(std::bind([tempDialog]() {
        tempDialog->show();
    }));
}
```

I think dialogBookBoat is an array so it will not exist after the function call.

Comment: Wt::WDialog * tempDialog=new Wt::WPushButton();
buttonBookBoat[i] = tempDialog; These two lines are wrong, but I fixed them and your code worked! THANK YOU